# AWS Aurora: converting an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster to provisioned

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm trying to convert an AWS Aurora database cluster (Postgres version) from Serverless v1 to provisioned. The cluster has been recently successfully upgraded from version 11.16 to 13.9.

I'm following the instructions here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.modifying.html#aurora-serverless.modifying.convert

... and my AWS CLI statement looks like this, which matches the documentation:

```
aws rds modify-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier <cluster name> --engine-mode provisioned --allow-engine-mode-change --db-cluster-instance-class db.r5.xlarge
```

... but I'm getting the following error, which suggests the options for the command are incorrect somehow:

```
Unknown options: --engine-mode, --allow-engine-mode-change, provisioned
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my AWS CLI to version 2.11.23 and was able to modify the cluster.